# Why do I need a force downcast to work with protocol arrays with a constraint

Tags: swift, protocols

This is my code:

```
import UIKit

protocol Test where Self: UIView {}

class MyView: UIView, Test {

}

let array: [Test] = [MyView()]

let view = array[0]

let myAlpha = (view as UIView).alpha //ERROR
```

The error is:

> error: 'Test' is not convertible to 'UIView'; did you mean to use
>   'as!' to force downcast?

Why the force downcast? The protocol can only be adopted by UIView, therefore every element in the array `array` IS-A `UIView`, right? Is there any case it is not a `UIView`, hence needing the downcast?

Comment: I don't have an answer to the *why* question in your title - I'd agree with your bottom paragraph. I'm guessing someone who knows more about the Swift type system can explain why that's not the case. However, you can define `typealias TestView = UIView & Test`, and then `let array: [TestView] = [MyView()]`, you won't get the error.

Comment: @Connor Yea it is really strange, it is really about the protocol I never get this weird behavior with classes/subclasses... That could be a solution but I am trying to find a way how it could crash because Swift really wants me to downcast

Comment: The clause `where Self: UIView {}` means that only instances **and subclasses** of `UIView` can adopt the protocol and did implement the protocol requirements – this is evaluated at **compile** time –   but it does not mean that `Test` objects are necessarily `UIView` instances.

Comment: @vadian yes, i did not think about it. I added an answer here :) Thank you

Comment: AFAIK being able to use class constraints in protocol `where` clauses isn't something that's fully supported currently – that's tracked by [SR-6001](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-6001) (and there are other sharp edges such as [SR-6816](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-6816)). Once it is supported though, I don't see any reason why you shouldn't be able to coerce a `Test` to a `UIView` (and otherwise do `UIView` things with it).

Comment: @vadian "*it does not mean that `Test` objects are necessarily `UIView` instances*" Why not? You said yourself that only `UIView` and its subclasses can conform to `Test`.

Comment: Worth noting that until the compiler supports this, you can workaround it with an underscored protocol and class existential typealias: https://gist.github.com/hamishknight/c047894531d92b35465dff6c90ea0c3e

Comment: looks like it has been fixed using xcode11.1 swift5.0

Answer (score 1):

I scratched my head and I know the answer to my own question. With only classes, this situation would never happen, but with protocols (and interfaces in Java), I could actually put in an other class inside the array, this is how:

```
import UIKit

protocol Test where Self: UIView {}

class MyView: UIView, Test {}

var array: [Test] = [MyView()]

let view = array[0]

class NotAUIView {}

let myFakeTestInstance = NotAUIView() as! Test

array.append(myFakeTestInstance) // Auch! Compiles but it does not conform to the protocol Test!!
```

It compiles, but crashes at runtime. Subclasses can adopt ofcourse the protocol Test, I did not think about it. Force-downcasting to protocols always compiles to any class without errors, but force-downcasting to other classes which will never work, will throw an warning from the compiler saying it will always fail.

Comment: FYI - `myFakeTestInstance` is of type `Test` due to the cast. So your comment isn't correct. This answer doesn't really address your question because you lied to the compiler by claiming that `NotAUIView` is really a `Test`. It compiles like it should. It crashes at runtime on the use of `NotAUIView() as! Test` because obviously it's not really a `Test`.

Comment: @rmaddy well I first was confused why I needed the downcast, because if it was done with classes only, so no protocols, you wouldn't need the force downcast. Since any class can later on adopt the protocol, it isn't guaranteed that the array contains only UIView elements. You are right about the comment, I will change that

Comment: Your edited comment is still wrong. The line `let myFakeTestInstance = NotAUIView() as! Test` is the same as `let myFakeTestInstance: Test = NotAUIView() as! Test`

Answer (score 0):

Since you define your array as containing `Test` objects with

```
let array: [Test] // <-- This
```

Then getting any object in that array will give you an instance of `Test`

```
let view = array[0] // <-- view is of type `Test
```

So if you know that this object will be of type `UIView` (which again, the compiler does not since you told it was a `Test` object), then you need to force cast.

Comment: Every Test instance MUST BE an instance of UIView. Why is the downcast needed?

Comment: I don't think the compiler is smart enough to understand that unfortunately.

Comment: Nah Swift is out for years now... The compiler should know that protocol is constrained I believe... I will wait if someone have an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the compiler does not recognize the type constraint (strict as it may be) as an actual inheritance.

You could work around this by extending your protocol to make it do the type cast itself, given that within the protocol, the identity of the class is known.

```
@objc protocol Test where Self:UIView {}

extension Test
{
   var asUIView: UIView { return self }
}

view.asUIView.alpha // will work
```

Note that you need to add @objc to your protocol declaration for this to work with a bridged class (UIView) which would not be necessary with a native Swift class.

Answer (score -1):

If you change the type of `array` to `[MyView]` you do not need the forced cast:

```
import UIKit

protocol Test where Self: UIView {}

class MyView: UIView, Test {}

let array: [MyView] = [MyView()]

let view = array[0]

let myAlpha = view.alpha
```

Comment: Yes haha, I do not get a compiler error here but this is clearly not what the question is about

Comment: Of course it is. You need the forced downcast because your array has the wrong type. How should the compiler know that it can cast the object `view` of type `Test` to `UIView ` in this case?

Comment: Because the protocol declaration is `protocol Test where Self: UIView {}`. So only `UIView`s should be able to be `Test`s. Which is the question asked

Comment: The question is why do I need to downcast a constrained protocol, to a type it is constrainted to

Comment: It just does not work this way. With `protocol Test where Self: UIView {}` you define that `Test` can only be used by `UIView` but `Test` still does not inherit from `UIView` and thus the compiler cannot cast the object.

Answer (score -2):

Update - fixed in Swift5 (Xcode11.1)

```
protocol TestProtocol where Self: UIView {
    func testCall()
}

extension TestProtocol {
    func testCall() {
        print("protocol #function")
    }
}

class MyView: UIView, TestProtocol {
    // if commented out then imnplementation in extension of TestProtocol
    func testCall() {
        print("instance #function")
    }
}

let array: [TestProtocol] = [MyView()]
let view = array[0]
let myAlpha = view.alpha
view.testCall()
```

Comment: Every Test instance MUST BE an instance of UIView. Why is the downcast needed? the compiler should know, every Test element IS-A UIView

Comment: Just because you see logical connection thru protocol, compiler doesn't due to declaration of array.